# Errors when invoking chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I built Fabric network using Kafka-based orderer service.
(2 peer, 1 orderer and 4 kafka)

When I invoke a chaincode, below message appears in peer's log.
[gossip/state] queueNewMessage -> WARN 7a24 Failed adding payload: Ledger height is at 5685, cannot enqueue block with sequence of 938

What is this message?
Can I ignore this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because the second peer's height is much less than the first peer's height, and it (the second peer) pulls from the orderer blocks that the first peer doesn't need, and forwards to it as a token of good will. 
The peer logs that he got a block he doesn't need.